# How to get the property value of a class based on property number

Tags: .net, vb.net, reflection, foreach, properties

I tried to search for an already posted answer, but was unable to find any, although some threads provided some hints.

What I normally do to set the same property across numbered instances of controls is something like:

```
  DirectCast(Me.Controls.Item("Picturebox" & port), PictureBox).Tag = "some tag"
```

Is there a similar approach if I want to loop around numbered properties class1.property1 to class1.property99 of a class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[CallByName](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/chsc1tx6(v=vs.80).aspx) is what you are looking for. I think it uses reflection under the bonnet (hood) so might not be that efficient:

```
For i As Integer = 1 to 99    
    CallByName(class1, "property" & i.ToString(), CallType.Set, "New Value")
Next
```

Comment: And what if I have a method associated with my 99 properties.

Comment: Read the docs and you will see that you need to use `CallType.Method`